# BroadcastReceiver to capture image from camera

Tags: android, image, camera, broadcastreceiver

I want a broadcastreceive that when the user take a picture on native camera I intercept this picture.

With this code:

```
<receiver android:name=".PictureReceiver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="10000" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When the user take a picture the PictureReceiver is activated but I dont know how or if is possible to get the picture taken

Answer (score 0):

There is no broadcast action available to filter the action, when the user take a picture.

Check in the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON, only "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" is available to detect the "camera button" pressed.